# Using pickle object of model to predict output

Tags: python, node.js, machine-learning, data-science, webdeploy

I have a build a ML model and exported it as pickle object file,**final goal is to use this object file to make prediction in web app.**

**What I want to know** 
How to use this pickle file to predict output in a Node.js server.Is it possible?If yes,can you explain how?

Comment: Are you running python in the server at all? Or just Node.js? What model is it? Simple polynomial model would be easy to export also to Node.js, but more complex models might require some more thinking.

Comment: I don't think you can load a pickle python model in Node. One simple way would be to create a simple API in Python using Flask to serve the model, and send requests with Node.

Comment: @np8 It's a linear regression model.
Thanks

Comment: @CoMartel Yes, now I moved to flask.
Thanks.

Comment: In case you need, a linear regression model is quite easily imported anywhere. What you would need to do is to export all the model coefficients in a json file, and then read the coefficients & create equation based on these.